# Not able to run process containing pre defined email service task in jbpm 6.1.0

Tags: java, remote-access, jbpm

I am using RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory (rest) i.e. RemoteRestRuntimeFactory to get KieSession and then starting aprocess which contains just one pre defined email service task. It is timing out every time no matter how much time out I give. The exception that is thrown on time out is 
    Exception in thread "main" org.kie.services.client.api.command.exception.  RemoteCommunicationException: Unable to post request: Read timed out

It seems that this was reported as a bug but it was not reproducible in version 6. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1012915

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be timing out due to the fact it cant reach an SMTP server? This was the time out issue for me.

Inside the war file at /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/CustomWorkItemHandlers.conf you can add the line...

```
"Email" : new org.jbpm.process.workitem.email.EmailWorkItemHandler("SMTP SERVER HERE","SMTP PORT","EMAIL ADDRESS","EMAIL PASSWORD")
```

This is how I set up the SMTP server.

Hopefully that does it for you like it did for me.